# Braided monoidal categories as doubly degenerate tricategories

Tags: reference-request, ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory

The fact that any tricategory with a single 0-cell and a single 1-cell is a braided monoidal category seems to be widely known. For instance, it appears in the "periodic table" of n-categories in [Baez and Shulman, *Lectures on n-categories and cohomology* (2006)](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0608420) and [the nLab page on Gray categories](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Gray-category).

> **Question.** Where can I find a proof of this result, based on a precise definition of tricategories?

Comment: I can make an official answer later, but I think you're looking for Cheng and Gurski's _The periodic table of n-categories II:degenerate tricategories_ https://arxiv.org/abs/0706.2307, published in Cahiers in 2011.